# SSH connection via USB to iPhone

Tags: iphone, usb, ssh

I want to connect to the SSH server on my jailbreaked iPhone via the USB connection (because that connection is much faster than WLAN) from MacOSX.

Right now I am using this: http://novis.jimdo.com/2009/10/18/ssh-relay-aka-iphone-tunnel-version-3/

However, this is really buggy and always breaks when I am transfering a lot of data.

Does anyone know a better solution? Preferable one that is free.

Comment: The one who gave the downvote here. Why?

Comment: @Albert there are no downvotes as of now.

Comment: Well there was one (at least it showed -1 for a short while), maybe he has removed it again.

Comment: I'd suggest finding why the connection is slow.

Comment: You mean why WLAN is slower than USB? That is simple: WLAN allows 54 MBit/sec, USB allows 480 MBit/sec.

Comment: 54Mbit a second, almost 8 MBytes a second. Can the iphone sustain a read/write at that rate
480 Mbit is 60Mbytes, that is the max possible speed, but is never reached.

Comment: Well, considering all the overhead and that I don't have a perfect connection, I have usually about 1-2 MByte/sec over WLAN (both on my MacBook, when I download from somewhere else and also from the iPhone). Over USB, I get about 20 MByte/sec, so it really much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iFunBox GUI app: http://blog.i-funbox.com/?page_id=1070 or python script https://marcansoft.com/blog/iphonelinux/usbmuxd/ to make SSH connection via USB